# Unable to add Jackson dependency qith scope *compile* to Maven plugin

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I'm working on a custom Maven plugin and need to perform some JSON processing. When I try to add the `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataform:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.15.1` dependency with the scope set to `compile` (or default), the plugin package phase fails. The only valid scope to make the plugin package correctly is to set the scope to `provided`, which allows the plugin to compile, but the classes are not available at runtime.

Can someone explain why I'm unable to add the plugin dependency with a default (compile) scope?

**Maven version**: 3.8.8

**JDK version**: 11.0.12

Here is a contrived example that demonstrates what's happening:

**Custom Plugin**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myplugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>myplugin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myplugin-maven-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>     <!-- PROVIDED MUST BE SPECIFIED IN ORDER TO PACKAGE PLUGIN-->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**MyMojo.java**

```java
package com.myplugin;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Goal which tests the plugin mojo.
 *
 * @goal test-mojo
 * 
 * @phase validate
 */
public class MyMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        // When dependency scope is "provided", this project using this plugin fails compilation
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    }
}
```

**Project using custom plugin**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my-plugin-tester</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin-tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myplugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>myplugin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.myplugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>myplugin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-mojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

In the above *Custom Plugin* `pom.xml`, when the `scope` of the Jackson dependency is set to `provided`, the plugin command `mvn clean install` works as expected, but when I try to reference the `XmlMapper` class at runtime, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.myplugin:myplugin-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:test-mojo(default) on project plugin-tester: Execution default of goal com.myplugin:myplugin-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:test-mojo failed: A required class was missing while executing com.myplugin:myplugin-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper

If I set the `scope` of the Jackson dependency to `compile` (or default), the command `mvn clean package -e` fails with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project myplugin-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project myplugin-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed.
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed.
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.objectweb.asm.Type.getObjectType (Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.visitors.MojoClassVisitor.visit (MojoClassVisitor.java:108)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept (Unknown Source)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept (Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scanFile (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:139)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:85)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.scanAnnotations (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:125)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:104)
> at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor (DefaultMojoScanner.java:108)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute (AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:233)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.DescriptorGeneratorMojo.execute (DescriptorGeneratorMojo.java:92)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)